# Fast report 4 Property DataOnly does not exist?

Tags: delphi-7, fastreport

I have a problem with Fast Report 4 component in Delphi 7.

[image]

I tried to recompile but it did not work.
Anyone know what is this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The message means that in a DFM file, there is a component named frxPDFExport which has a property named DataOnly but the actual component installed in the IDE lacks that property.

This happens when a form or frame or datamodule has been created when a different version of the component was installed compared to the installed version when you reopen the form, frame of datamodule.

To solve the issue, you have to cancel this error message and you have to install the same component version, then reload the file.

You can also ignore the message and that property won't be loaded. Surely you have to update the code and other property values to accommodate with the different component version.